# How to redirect shopify default shop checkout page to private App checkout page?

Tags: laravel-5, shopify-app

I have created shopify private checkout app in laravel and installed with a demo shop. Private app  has installed successfully with shop, but  I have no idea to how it redirect default checkout page to created private app checkout page in shopify shop. Could you please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only shopify plus merchant can customize checkout page , you already posted question in shopify community. You can only update limited information in shopify checkout:

These help articles contain general information about what can and cannot be changed on the payment screen:

[Online payment screen](https://help.shopify.com/es/manual/checkout-settings)

[Customize the style of your payment screen](https://help.shopify.com/es/manual/checkout-settings/checkout-style)

[Edit the payment screen options](https://help.shopify.com/es/manual/checkout-settings/checkout-form-options)